# Download problem with macOS Big Sur 11.1 Update

Tags: macos-big-sur

I have tried several times (using different WiFi networks) to download update macOS Big Sur 11.1 but every time download failed. I have received the same message:

Download failed
An error occurred while downloading the selected updates. Please check your internet connection and try again.

I am using MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with macOS Big Sur Version 11.0.1

Comment: Can you find anything in the system logs? I'm not sure which log you need to look at specifically. But as it stands there isn't enough information here to help you really.

Comment: Did you check with software update from mac itself? Also does it stop after a while or it just doesn't start at all?

Comment: I used System Preferences/Software Update to download macOS Big Sur 11.1 . It has 4,19 GB and It stops at the end of the process with message Download failed.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. It's probably less space on the drive. Deleting some files and increase space on drive helped me.

Comment: Same issue occurred while installing macOS 11.2.3. Increasing available free space on drive was the solution.